# ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.data'

Tags: tensorflow

My tensorflow version is 1.1.0
I try to import some file:
    **strong textfrom tensorflow.contrib.data import Dataset, Iterator**
and got error :
    **ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.data'**
So, what is solution of this?

Comment: Did you try `tensorflow.data` also/instead?

Comment: yes i tried...but got same importError

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tf.contrib.data** has been deprecated and been removed (Check [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/contrib/data/README.md)). So, in order to import "Dataset" and "iterator", follow the following steps:

1. You need to upgrade the tensorflow version using:
   `sudo pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`.
   Check the installation guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/)
2. Open the python terminal and type

   `import tensorflow as tf`

   `dataset = tf.data.Dataset`

Hope it will help.